# FullCalendar Angular Drag and Drop Resize is not working

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar, resize

I’m trying to deploy fullcalendar in my Angular APP but when i drop the event into the weekview i can not resize the event, is like is dupplicate. When i resize is look like:

[image]

I tried all...i read the whole Fullcalendar documentation

All...i read the whole Fullcalendar documentation

```
<div class="row" pDroppable="eventoDraggable"  (onDrop)="drop($event,eventoDraggable)">
    <div class="btn mt-3" title="Borrar prioridad">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="row" id='external-events'>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <p-table [value]="eventosTrabajo" class="p-datatable-sm">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                    <th  style="width: 33%;" >
                    <span>Trabajo</span>
                    <button class="btn mt-3" (click)="abrirModal('Trabajo')" title="Añadir prioridad">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>

                </th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-evento>
                <tr>
                    <td id='evento.id' class="fc-event" pDraggable="eventoDraggable" (onDragStart)="dragStart(evento)" (onDragEnd)="dragEnd($event)">{{evento.title}}</td>
                    <!-- <td class="fc-event" pDraggable="trabajo" (onDragStart)="dragStart(evento)" (onDragEnd)="dragEnd($event)">{{evento.title}}</td> -->
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
        





        <p-table [value]="eventosRelaciones" class="p-datatable-sm">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                    <th  style="width: 33%;" >Relaciones</th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-evento>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{evento.title}}</td>                
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
    
        <p-table [value]="eventosPersonal" class="p-datatable-sm">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                    <th  style="width: 34%;" >Personal</th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-evento>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{evento.title}}</td>  
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-11">

        <div class='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
            <label>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                [checked]='calendarOptions.weekends'
                (change)='handleWeekendsToggle()'
              />
              toggle weekends
            </label>
          </div>
        
            <!-- <full-calendar id='calendar' [options]="calendarOptions" (eventDrop)="handleEventDrop($event)"></full-calendar> -->

            <!-- <div id="kt_docs_fullcalendar_drag"></div> -->
            <full-calendar *ngIf='calendarVisible' [options]='calendarOptions'>
                <ng-template #eventContent let-arg>
                  <b>{{ arg.timeText }}</b>
                  <i>{{ arg.event.title }}</i>
                </ng-template>
              </full-calendar>


            <!-- <div id='calendar-container'>
                <div id='calendar'></div>
            </div> -->
        
    </div>

</div>

import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar, CalendarOptions, DateSelectArg, EventApi, EventClickArg, EventInput, EventSourceInput } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import interactionPlugin , { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import { duration } from 'moment';
import { CalendarioService } from '../../services/calendario.service';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { FullCalendarComponent } from '@fullcalendar/angular';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-diasemana',
  templateUrl: './diasemana.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./diasemana.component.css']
})
export class DiasemanaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public eventosService: CalendarioService,
              private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }


  public contador: number = 1;

  //public calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  public containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
  public draggableEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
  
  public evento: EventApi = {};
  public eventoDraggable: EventApi = {};
  public eventos: any[] = [];
  
  public eventosTrabajo: EventInput [] = []
  public eventosRelaciones = [] 
  public eventosPersonal = []
  
  //public eventosTrabajo = [{id:"1",title:"Documentar"},{id:"2",title:"Reuniones"}, {id:"3",title:"Proyectos"}, {id:"4",title:"Planificar"}, {id:"5",title:"Emails y Llamadas"}, {id:"6",title:"Incidencias"}]
  // public eventosRelaciones = [{title:"Ramon"}, {title:"Familia"}, {title:"Amigos"}]
  // public eventosPersonal = [{title:"Leer"}, {title:"Meditar"}, {title:"Hobbies"}, {title:"Descansar"}, {title:"Nutrición"}]
  
  
  public calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    plugins: [
      interactionPlugin,
      timeGridPlugin,
    ],
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      // left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
      //right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    //navLinks: true,
    //themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
    editable: true,
    //eventStartEditable: true,
    //expandRows: true,
    locale: 'es',
    firstDay: 1,
    //height: 850,
    droppable: true,
    weekNumbers: true,
    weekends: true,
    //selectable: true,
    //selectMirror: true,
    //dayMaxEvents: true,
    eventResizableFromStart: true,
    eventDisplay: 'block',
    eventOverlap: true,
    eventStartEditable: true, // Habilita la opción de arrastrar y soltar solo para el inicio del evento
    eventDrop: (info) => this.handleEventDrop(info),
    drop: (info) => this.drop1(info),
    // eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
    eventResize:  (info) => this.resize(info.event),
    //dateClick: (info) => this.handleDateClick(info.date),
    //dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), // MUST ensure `this` context is maintained
    events: this.eventosTrabajo,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
    eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
    eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this),
    eventDragStart: function(a) {
      console.log("Drag start", a);
    },
    eventDragStop: function(a) {
      console.log("Drag stop", a);
    
    },
    
    
  };




  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.draggableEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
    this.containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
    //this.dragStart(this.evento)
    
    //this.containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
//     var containerEl = document.getElementById("external-events");
//     new Draggable(containerEl!, {
//     itemSelector: ".fc-event",
//     eventData: function(eventEl) {
//         return {
//             title: eventEl.innerText.trim()
//         }
//     }
//     });

//     var calendarEl = document.getElementById("kt_docs_fullcalendar_drag");
//     var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl!, {
//       initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
//       plugins: [
//         interactionPlugin,
//         timeGridPlugin,
//       ],
//     editable: true,
//     droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar

// });

// calendar.render();

this.cargarEventosCategoria()

    
    
  }
  

  public calendarVisible = true;

  handleCalendarToggle() {
    this.calendarVisible = !this.calendarVisible;
  }

  handleWeekendsToggle() {
    const { calendarOptions } = this;
    calendarOptions.weekends = !calendarOptions.weekends;
  }

  handleDateSelect(selectInfo: DateSelectArg) {
    const title = prompt('Please enter a new title for your event');
    const calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;

    calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection

    if (title) {
      calendarApi.addEvent({
        id: '123',
        title,
        start: selectInfo.startStr,
        end: selectInfo.endStr,
        allDay: selectInfo.allDay
      });
    }
  }

  handleEventClick(clickInfo: EventClickArg) {
    if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`)) {
      clickInfo.event.remove();
    }
  }

  handleEvents(events: EventApi[]) {
    this.eventos = events;
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }
  
  dragStart(evento:EventApi) {
    this.eventoDraggable = evento

    this.draggableEl = document.getElementById(evento._id!);

    new Draggable(this.containerEl!, {
      itemSelector: '.fc-event',
      eventData: function(eventEl) {
        return {
          title: eventEl.innerText,
          duration: '02:00'
        };
      }
    });

 
  }

  resize(eventInfo: any){
    
  }

  
  
  
  dragEnd($event: any) {
    
    this.eventoDraggable = {}
    
 
    
  }

  handleEventDrop(eventInfo: any) {

    console.log('hola, has metido algoo');
    

    this.evento._id = eventInfo.event._id
    this.evento.title = eventInfo.event.title
    this.evento.start = eventInfo.event.start
    this.evento.end = eventInfo.event.end


    // const event = eventInfo;
    // const start = event.start;
    // const end = event.end;
    // const id = eventInfo._def.extendedProps._id
    
    // let eventoGuardado: EventApi = {}
    
    // eventoGuardado.start = start
    // eventoGuardado.end = end
    // eventoGuardado._id = id
    // eventoGuardado.duration = '00:30'
    // eventoGuardado.title = event.title 
    
    
    // this.eventosService.crearEventoCategoria(eventoGuardado)
    // .subscribe( (resp:any) => {

    //   this.cargarEventosCategoria();
      
    // });
  }

  drop1(enventInfo:any){
    console.log('has soltado algo dentro del calendario');
    
  }

  
  handleDateClick(fecha:Date) {

  }

  cargarEventosCategoria(){
    
      this.eventosService.cargarEventosCategoria()
      .subscribe( resp => {
        
        this.eventosTrabajo = resp.eventos;       

        this.calendarOptions.events = this.eventosTrabajo
        

        
        
      })

  }

  async abrirModal(categoria:string){
    

    const { value = '' } = await Swal.fire<string>({
      title: `Añadir Prioridad`,
      text: `Nueva prioridad`,
      input: 'text',
      inputPlaceholder: 'Prioridad',
      showCancelButton: true,
    });


    if( value.trim().length > 0 ) {

      const evento: EventApi = {}
      evento.title = value
      evento.categoria = categoria
      evento.draggable = true
      
    
  
      evento.editable = true
    //   evento.color = {
    //     "primary":this.colorEscogido,
    //     "secondary":this.colorEscogido
    // }
  
  
      this.eventosService.crearEventoCategoria(evento)
      .subscribe( (resp:any) => {
  
        this.cargarEventosCategoria();
            
      });
    }

    }

  crearEvento(titulo:string,categoria:string){

    const evento: EventApi = {}
    evento.title = titulo
    evento.categoria = categoria
  

    evento.editable = true
  //   evento.color = {
  //     "primary":this.colorEscogido,
  //     "secondary":this.colorEscogido
  // }


    this.eventosService.crearEvento(evento)
    .subscribe( (resp:any) => {

      this.cargarEventosCategoria();
          
    });
  }


  drop($event: any, evento: EventApi){
  
    
    if (this.eventoDraggable) {
      return Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Borrar el evento?',
        text: `Esta a punto de borrar a ${ evento.title }`,
        icon: 'question',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Sí, borrarlo'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          
          this.eventosService.eliminarEvento( evento )
            .subscribe( resp => {
              
              this.cargarEventosCategoria();
              Swal.fire(
                'Evento borrado',
                `${ evento.title } fue eliminado correctamente`,
                'success'
              );
              
            });

        }
      })
  
    }else{
      return null
    }
  }


}
```